# Let $P$ be a prime ideal in the ring of integers then $P \cap \Bbb Z$ is prime in $\Bbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals, dedekind-domain

Let $P$ be a prime ideal in the ring of integers $O_K$ then $P \cap \Bbb Z=<p>$ for some prime $p \in \Bbb Z$.

So what I have to prove is that $P \cap \Bbb Z$ is prime in $\Bbb Z$.

Now $ab \in P \cap \Bbb Z$ then either $a \in  P $ or $b \in  P $. How do I prove that either of them are in $\Bbb Z$

Comment: You have to assume $a,b\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Why is it so? $ab \in \Bbb Z$.

Comment: You have to prove that $P\cap\mathbb Z$ is a prime ideal *in $\mathbb Z$*. This means that if we have $a,b$ *in $\mathbb Z$* with $ab\in P\cap\mathbb Z$, then either $a$ or $b$ is in $P\cap\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Yes, you are right! Thanks a lot.

Comment: As a remark, this is a corollary of a much more general result: let $f : A\to B$ be a map of (unital, commutative) rings. If $\mathfrak{p}\subseteq B$ is a prime ideal, then $\mathfrak{q} = f^{-1}(\mathfrak{p})$ is a prime ideal in $A.$ Proof: if $ab\in\mathfrak{q},$ then $f(ab) = f(a)f(b)\in\mathfrak{p}.$ As $\mathfrak{p}$ is prime, this implies that one of $f(a)$ or $f(b)$ is in $\mathfrak{p},$ hence one of $a$ or $b$ is in $\mathfrak{q}$. $\blacksquare$ Now, your result follows by letting $f : \Bbb{Z}\to\mathcal{O}_K$ be the canonical inclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you ask at the end is not true, consider $K = \mathbb Q(i)$. Then $\mathcal O_K = \mathbb Z [i]$. Consider the ideal $P = \langle 1+i \rangle$, which is prime. Then we have that $1+i$ and $1-i$ are both in $P$ and not in $\mathbb Z$, but
$(1+i)(1-i)=2$ is in $\mathbb Z.$

So you have to assume that $a,b \in \mathbb Z$.

Back to the general case. Suppose $P$ is a prime ideal in $\mathcal O_K$. Then whenever $ab\in P$ for $a,b\in \mathbb Z \subset \mathcal O_K$ we have that either $a \in P$ or $b \in P$. Thus, $P \cap \mathbb Z$ is a prime ideal. Since $\mathbb Z$ is a principal ideal domain, $P \cap \mathbb Z$ has the desired form.

Comment: Yes, you are right! Thanks a lot.